# Should translations of X-GNOME-* extension keys be stripped from desktop entry files and put in language packs instead?

Tags: translation

To save disk space, all packages in the main repository have translations of the "Name", "GenericName" and "Comment" keys stripped from their *.desktop files, and put in language packs instead.

However, lots of packages in main (for example, Inkscape) also contain multiple translations of GNOME extension keys such as "X-GNOME-FullName".  Is there any reason why these keys are not stripped from the *.desktop files, or would it make sense to update the package mangler to do this?

Comment: Note that I asked a similar question at Launchpad a week ago, but received no reply as yet.  Please forgive me if this is the wrong thing to do... I'm new to askubuntu!

Comment: See [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pkgbinarymangler/+question/156651)

Comment: I believe you should file a bug report, your question is specific to a particular low level change in Ubuntu, I am not sure this is the best place to get feedback with that.

Comment: I've created a [new bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/783565) proposing the change... however, I'm not sure whether it would be a good idea or not.  Any opinions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This was not done to save disk space as the space saved is insignficant. It was instead done so that Ubuntu could translate the .desktop names directly in Launchpad which gets pushed out via language pack updates.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that.  Is there a reason why this is not used for the X-GNOME-* keys too?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards